# Openlayers Layerswitcher constraints

Tags: openlayers-2

Im building a kind of webgis with openlayers with a couple of overlay Layers.

Is there a possibility to implement some constraints to the layerswitcher?

My idea is to have two lists of layers and from both list you can choose only one Layer a time. The result should be that there are maximum two overlays at the map.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well your problem, I don't think that logic has to be at the layer switcher control. You could control this registering some code to the layer visibility events and sharing an object to create something like two sets of base layers, so when a layer is selected, all the rest of layers of its group are switched off.

Comment: Thank you, I have to think about that and try this, but I think i will not work for my purpose. I want to have to sets of layers (made with d3.js) for example population density and so on in one list shown as a choropleth map an a second list of layers as pie charts or circle overlays. So that the user can combine them.